# Angular forms: pass error to form from one of group

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm sorry if it's duplicate of some question, I didn't find any solution for my problem.

I have two form groups from `@angular/forms` in Angular 5 app. One of them has custom validator that set an error. One of group has error and form is invalid, but form doesn't has any errors inside. How can I prevent it and display error correctly?

Creating form

```
private createForm() {
    const groups = {};

    this.groupArray.forEach((item, index) => {
        const group: SomModel<FormControl> = { thing: this.fb.control(thing.id, [Validators.required]) };

        groups['thing' + index] = index === 0 ?
            this.fb.group(group) :
            this.fb.group(group, { validator: this.thingMatchValidator(groups['thing' + (index - 1)].controls.thing) });
    });

    this.form = this.fb.group(groups);
}
```

Validator

```
thingMatchValidator(from: Dictionary<FormControl>): ValidatorFn {
    return (to: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {  // seems that I soudn't use AbstractControl because I have FormGroup here
        const thingFrom = from.thing.value;
        const thingTo = to.value.thing;
        const test = thingFrom && thingTo && thingFrom === thingTo ? { portMatch: true } : null;
        return test;
    };
}
```

Update:

The field that I need to validate stayed valid, but form is invalid.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code where you have added the validator in your form builder ?

Comment: @Niladri I updated question